# Creating grpc server and client python interfaces from URL

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I was wondering if it is possible to generate the interfaces from a git repository location instead of relative directory locations.

I tried

```sh
python -m grpc.tools.protoc \
    --proto_path=https://github..../../protos/ \
    --grpc_python_out=. https://github..../..protos/required.proto
```

but it doesn't work with the error `https://github..../../protos/required.proto: No such file or directory exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported in any protobuf implementation I know of. You'll have to download the proto files indicated somehow as well as all of their dependencies.